# Query Location With kilometer Radius in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called restaurants.. and also i have formatted into geoJSON and I tried to query the following way

```
db.restaurants.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

I have mentioned radius 5/3963.2 (calculation in miles).. but I need radius distance in kilometer like `{ $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5] }`

I need to mentioned radius in kilometer

How to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MongoDB expects values in radians.

To convert distance to radians, simply divide the distance value to the radius of the sphere (earth), where:

3963.2 is radius of earth in Miles.

6378.1 is radius of earth in Km.

```
db.restaurants.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 5 / 6378.1 ] } } })
```

Comment: if you dont mine pls explain this calculation.. what is the value 6378.1@Sergiu Zaharie

Comment: and also i have another doubt.. i have used mongo compass.. how to do this same query in mongo compass @ mr. Sergiu Zaharie

Comment: so `5/ 6378.1` means 5 km and 0.5/6378.1 means 500 meter.. this my understand is correct

Comment: Thank u @Sergiu Zaharie

Comment: Oh, yes, the magic earth-radius numbers. The Napoleonic definition of *kilometre* defined it as one part in ten thousand of the distance from the equator to the pole or 90 degrees. (Dictators like to keep things simple.)  So, 10,000/90 = 111.111 km per degree. That's 6,366.2 km per radian. The actual number, in temperate latitudes is closer to 111.318, and so that's where you get 6378.1 km per radian. (The earth isn't perfectly spherical, dictatorial degrees notwithstanding.)   When you're working with GPS distances there are inaccuracies. *Close* works in the game of horseshoes and with GPS.

Comment: Nice Explanation Mr. O,Jones Really helpful for me Thank u Mr O.Jones @O.Jones

Comment: this is inaccurate, the radius of the earth is 6,371 km

Comment: @O.Jones math adds up but on mongo's docs it says that "The circle's radius, as measured in the units used by the coordinate system." and the coordinate system given is in degrees so shouldn't the radius be divided instead by 111.111?